# how to query M2M with related_name

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have two really similar models with M2M field, somehow I tried to query one of them which works perfectly but when I try the same code with the other one, it gives me errors.  The only difference I can find is the `related_name`

I found a workaround but I am still curious how can I get this to work if I met the same problem next time.

(I only wrote the M2M field I have, and each model only has one M2M field, even though come to think of it, what can be done if there are more than one M2M, but this is out of this question)

this is the working model I have

```
class Team(View):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
```

this is the view with the above model, (skipping the `class`, the `def post` and so on)

```
user = User.objects.filter(id=111).first()
all_members = user.Team_set.filter()  # this would return all
```

below is the model that is giving me problems

```
class Room(View):
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='participants')
```

this is the view with the above model

```
user = User.objects.filter(id=111).first()
all_p = user.room_set.filter()  # this then gives me error of 'User' object has no attribute 'room_set'
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining `related_name` you need to use it like this:

```
Model.related_name.*
```

the alias `related_model_set` gets destroyed.

With that said your code should look like:

```
user = User.objects.filter(id=111).first()
all_p = user.participants.filter()  # this then gives me error of 'User' object has no attribute 'room_set'
```

Comment: ah! ok, so it'll make it like a field of `user`

Comment: that did work~ thx thx, but need to wait for a few minutes until I can accept answer

Comment: @Tsuna glad it helped!